# Decomposition of Normal Field Extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am trying to prove the following homework problem:

> Let $K/k$ be a normal field extension and $K_i$ and $K_s$ be intermediate extensions so that $K_i/k$ and $K/K_s$ are purely inseparable and $K_s/k$ and $K/K_i$ are separable. Show that $K=K_i\cdot{K_s}$ and $K_i \cap K_s=k$.

Showing $K_s \cap K_i =k$ is simple. Proving $K=K_i \cdot{K_s}$ seems a bit harder. My question is the following:

> Is the condition $K=K_i \cdot K_s$ equivalent to showing $K_i\setminus k$ and $K_s \setminus k$ form a partition of $K\setminus k$?

I dont think this is correct, because I cannot see how the hypothesis of normality comes into play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to see that $K=K_i\cdot K_s$ and it does not use normality of $K/k$:    I'll leave that to you.
However the result cannot be obtained (in general) without assuming $K/k$ to be normal.
$$ ?????$$
The key to the paradox is that normality of    $K/k$ is a sufficient condition for   the existence  of a subfield $K_i\subset K$ such   $K/K_i$ is separable *and* $K_i/K$ is purely inseparable !
For a general algebraic extension $K/k$, no such $K_i$ exists .
Indeed $K_i$ can only be the   the perfect  closure $k^{p^{-\infty}}$ of $k$ in $K$, but in general   $K$ won't be separable over  $k^{p^{-\infty}}$.
 A counterexample and further explanations can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66178/why-isnt-the-perfect-closure-separable/66242#66242).

**Edit: a hint**
To prove that $K=K_i\cdot K_s$ (the original question!) it is enough to show that $K$ is both separable and purely inseparable over $K_i\cdot K_s$.

Comment: I'm unsure why the containment $K \subseteq K_i \cdot K_s$ is easy to see. Letting $x \in K$ and assuming $x \not \in K_i \cdot K_s$ seems to pose no immediate problems. Perhaps I am going in the wrong direction and just not seeing the obvious.

Comment: Dear Holdsworth88, I have added a hint in an Edit to my answer. Feel free to tell me if it doesn't suffice.